# OpenCV vs Matlab time of execution and optimizations

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, opencv, image-processing

i'm going to implement the equalization proposed in a paper.
the method consists of substitute each value of each channel with the formula
in the 16th slide of this presentantion [slides](http://cilab.knu.ac.kr/seminar/Seminar/2005/20050513%28illuminant%20and%20device%20invariant%20colour%20using%20histogram%20equalisation%29.pdf)
First of all i've implemeted this equalization function in Matlab in two ways: in the first i compute the histograms (counts) of each channel in order to know
the number of values less then a specific value in the range [0 255]. Alternatively, in the second way i use some matrix operations (R<=value... G<=value .... V<=value).
Initially, i've thought that the second method was the best in terms of time to execution but it seems not.. and I was surprised for the first time.

Then i've implemented this function in OpenCV, and i'm now surprised because the execution in Matlab is faster then C++!! Using Matlab i have these timer values

Matlab, method 1: 1,36 seconds

Matlab, method 2: 1,74 seconds

In C++ using OpenCV i found these values:
OpenCV, method 1: 2380 milliseconds
OpenCV, method 2: 4651 milliseconds

I obtained the same results so the function is correct, but i think there is something wrong or something that could be enhanched in terms of computation time due to my inexperience in OpenCV because i expect that a compiled C++ function is faster than Matlab!!.... So my question is about how can i optimize the C++ code. In the following i put the C++ code using both methods

```
//I have an RGB image in the Mat 'image'

    Mat channel[3];

    // Splitting method 1
    split(image, channel);
    Mat Red, Green, Blue;
    Blue = channel[0];
    Green = channel[1];
    Red = channel[2];

    //Splitting method 2
    // Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
//  vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
//  split(image, bgr_planes);

    double maxB, maxG, maxR, Npx;
    double min;
    double coeffB, coeffG, coeffR;
    Mat newB, newG, newR;
    Mat mapB, mapG, mapR;
    int P_Bi, P_Gi, P_Ri;
    Mat rangeValues;
    double intpart;
    double TIME;

    int histSize = 256;

    /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange = { range };

    bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

    Mat countB, countG, countR;

    //Start the timer for the method 1
    TIME = (double)getTickCount();
    // Compute the histograms
    calcHist(&Blue, 1, 0, Mat(), countB, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&Green, 1, 0, Mat(), countG, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&Red, 1, 0, Mat(), countR, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);

    // Get the max from each channel
    minMaxLoc(Blue, &min, &maxB);
    minMaxLoc(Green, &min, &maxG);
    minMaxLoc(Red, &min, &maxR);

    //Number of pixels
    Npx = Blue.rows * Blue.cols;

    // Compute the coefficient of the formula
    coeffB = maxB / Npx;
    coeffG = maxG / Npx;
    coeffR = maxR / Npx;

    //Initialize the new channels
    newB = Mat(Blue.rows, Blue.cols, Blue.type(), cvScalar(0));
    newG = Mat(Green.rows, Green.cols, Green.type(), cvScalar(0));
    newR = Mat(Red.rows, Red.cols, Red.type(), cvScalar(0));

    //For each value of the range
    for (int value = 0; value < 255; value++)
    {
        mapB = (Blue == value)/255;
        mapG = (Green == value)/255;
        mapR = (Red == value)/255;

        //Number of pixels less or equal then 'value'
        rangeValues = countB(Range(0, value+1), Range(0, 1));
        P_Bi = cv::sum(rangeValues)[0];

        rangeValues = countG(Range(0, value + 1), Range(0, 1));
        P_Gi = cv::sum(rangeValues)[0];

        rangeValues = countR(Range(0, value + 1), Range(0, 1));
        P_Ri = cv::sum(rangeValues)[0];

        //Substitution of the value in the new channel plane
        modf((coeffB * P_Bi), &intpart);
        newB = newB + mapB * intpart;

        modf((coeffG * P_Gi), &intpart);
        newG = newG + mapG * intpart;

        modf((coeffR * P_Ri), &intpart);
        newR = newR + mapR * intpart;
    }


    TIME = 1000 * ((double)getTickCount() - TIME) / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 1 - elapsed time: " << TIME << "milliseconds." << endl;

    //Here it takes 2380 milliseconds
    //....
    //....
    //....

    //Start timer of method 2
    TIME = 0;
    TIME = (double)getTickCount();

    //Get the max
    minMaxLoc(Blue, &min, &maxB);
    minMaxLoc(Green, &min, &maxG);
    minMaxLoc(Red, &min, &maxR);

    Npx = Blue.rows * Blue.cols;

    coeffB = maxB / Npx;
    coeffG = maxG / Npx;
    coeffR = maxR / Npx;

    newB = Mat(Blue.rows, Blue.cols, Blue.type(), cvScalar(0));
    newG = Mat(Green.rows, Green.cols, Green.type(), cvScalar(0));
    newR = Mat(Red.rows, Red.cols, Red.type(), cvScalar(0));

    Mat mask = cvCreateImage(Blue.size(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    for (int value = 0; value < 255; value++)
    {

        mapB = (Blue == value) / 255;
        mapG = (Green == value) / 255;
        mapR = (Red == value) / 255;

        //Instead, there i used matrices operations
        mask = (Blue <= value)/255;
        P_Bi = cv::sum(mask)[0];

        mask = (Green <= value) / 255;
        P_Gi = cv::sum(mask)[0];

        mask = (Red <= value) / 255;
        P_Ri = cv::sum(mask)[0];


        modf((coeffB * P_Bi), &intpart);
        newB = newB + mapB * intpart;

        modf((coeffG * P_Gi), &intpart);
        newG = newG + mapG * intpart;

        modf((coeffR * P_Ri), &intpart);
        newR = newR + mapR * intpart;
    }

    //End of the timer
    TIME = 1000 * ((double)getTickCount() - TIME) / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 2 - elapsed time: " << TIME << "milliseconds." << endl;
    //Here it takes 4651 milliseconds
```

Comment: Is this a release build?

Comment: No i'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and these are the results of the esecution of the debug version while i'm writing the code of my project

Comment: I have seen cases where the debug build of Visual Studio is 100 times slower than the release build (yes 100 times slower!). You should not compare debug build timings.

Comment: If you switch to a release build to benchmark remember you must not mix debug and release meaning make sure the entire project is built in release including all dlls that you use. With Visual Studio it is not generally safe to mix debug and release since causes you to have more than 1 independent heap (which leads to heap corruption).

Comment: Ok so you think that is just because it is the debug build... If i want to try the performance of the release i ve just to switch to release and run? And then i will switch again to debug and continue to develop my code

Comment: I would expect an improvement if you switch to release. ***i ve just to switch to release and run?*** Yes make sure you have the opencv release libraries selected in your release config.